# Pegar valor de um select no angular

Tags: angular, html-select

Bom dia! Eu preciso pegar um valor de um select para conseguir passar o valor para o outro, porém sou novo em angular e html...

Codigo do select:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control" >
        <option selected>Selecione...</option>
        <option *ngFor="let tipo of tipos">{{tipo.Codigo}} - {{tipo.Nome}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Como eu disse antes, preciso primeiro pegar o codigo do select. Agradeço desde já ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sei que já faz tempo a questão. Mas, eu também procurei e custei achar a resposta. Como consegui, irei responder. Para futuras consultas.

**No HTML:**

```
<select class="form-control" type="number" [(ngModel)]="cidadeId" (ngModelChange)="onAddCidade()" >
  <option *ngFor="let cidades of cidade" [ngValue]="cidades.Id">
    <p>{{ cidades.Id }}, {{ cidades.NomeCidade }}, {{ cidades.PaisCidade }}</p>
  </option>
</select>
```

**Onde:**

**type="number"** -> Tipo da variável que irá pegar.

**[(ngModel)]="cidadeId"** -> Campo da variável que irá para o component

**[ngValue]="cidades.Id"** -> Esse campo será qual você quer pegar

**(ngModelChange)="onAddCidade()"** -> Função que irá ser chamada para executar algo ao selecionar.

*No caso do exemplo acima, está pegando o campo Id do objeto Cidades.*

**No Component:**

```
cidadeId: number; // Declaração da variável (Precisa ter o Mesmo nome da ngModel.).
  //id: number
  onAddCidade(){ // Função que foi chamada
    this.cidadeId = +this.cidadeId;
    console.log("estou no cidade compo... " + this.cidadeId); // Imprimiu o valor no Console log.
    console.log(this.number) // outra forma de imprimir.
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu fiz da seguinte forma pra pegar o valor do options, estou usando formulários reativos pra isso.

```
<label>Gênero</label>
        <select class="form-control mb-3" formControlName="sex">
            <option hidden >Selecione</option>
            <option>Masculino</option>
            <option>Feminino</option>
            <option>Unissex</option>
        </select>
```

sendo que meu formControlName="sex" esta apontando para um formgroup

```
 this.registerProducts = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: [null, Validators.required],
      description: [null, Validators.required],
      sex: [null, Validators.required],
      valueItem: [null, Validators.required],
      fileImage: [null], 
    });
```

bom peguei o valor do options, colocando o formControlName na tag select