# <select> com Angular

Tags: html5, angular

Boa noite, estou com uma duvida que não estou conseguindo resolver...

Estou tentando recuperar um objeto de um  e a variavel sempre volta undefined

Segue trecho de código:

HTML

```
<div class="modal fade add-treatment" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel"
      aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Adicionar Tratamento</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
              <select class="form-control" (ngModelChange)="selectTreatment($event)" name="selectTreatment" (ngModel)="selectTreatment" style="margin-top:25px;height: 34px;">
                <option [ngValue]="treatment" *ngFor="let treatment of treatments">{{treatment.name}}</option>
              </select>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button style="margin-right:15.5px" type="button" id="botaoAdicionarProduto" class="btn btn-success"
              (click)="addTreatment()">Adicionar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Arquivo.TS

```
private treatment: Treatment = new Treatment();


addTreatment(): void {

    console.log(this.treatment)

    this.customerService.addTreatment(this.customer, this.treatment).subscribe(response => {
      let res: Response = <Response>response;
      if (res.codigo == 1) {
        alert(res.mensagem);
        this.customer = new Customer();
      }
      else {
        alert(res.mensagem);
      }
    },
      (erro) => {
        alert(erro);
      });
  }


  selectTreatment(selctedTreatment: Treatment): void{
  this.treatment = selctedTreatment;
  console.log("Object: " + this.treatment.name);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Opa, encontrei a resposta em um outro post, vou deixar aqui o link para que os próximos a utilizem.

[Resolução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/305124/pegar-valor-de-um-select-no-angular?rq=1)